# Speech Recognition Handler

Tags: android, handler, speech

This is my first time posting here.

I'm new to Android Studio.

I'd like to create a handler for google speech recognition.

This is the main class

```
package com.example.recnonocimientodevoz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Index extends Activity {

    private Button boton;
    private EditText texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
        boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton);
        texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texto);
        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                VRecognition VR = new VRecognition();
                VR.startRecognition();
                texto.setText(VR.getResult());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the handler

```
package com.example.recnonocimientodevoz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VRecognition extends Activity{

    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private String phrase = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
    }

    public VRecognition(){
    }

    public void startRecognition (){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            phrase = result.get(0);
        }
    }
    public String getResult(){
        return phrase;
    }
}
```

I have debugged the code and found that it crashes when `onActivityResult` is called.

I hope you can help me. thanks

Comment: please post the logcat to see the exact description of the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i;
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),VRecognition.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

and change VRecognition Activity as

```
public class VRecognition extends Activity{
private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private String phrase = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startRecognition();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        phrase = result.get(0);
    }
}


public void startRecognition(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

}

Comment: Hi Harish, thanks for your help. I would like to have 2 classes, one will be the interface and the other will return the Result, the idea is to call that method from many interfaces .

Comment: do you want VRecognition class to be an Activity that can be called from many Activities?

Comment: thats right, excuse me for my ignorance, as i said before I'm new programming on android devices. If you could help me it would be nice. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code,  here is connected method is used to check the network connectivity, without that speech recognition wont work...

You should also use permissions in android manifest like this

```
AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then code

```
    public class SpeechRecognition extends Activity {
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
        Button Start;
        TextView Speech;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_reg);
            Speech = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.speech);

            Start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isConnected()){
                 Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                 RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                         }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Plese Connect to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }}

            });   
    }


    public  boolean isConnected()
        { 
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo net = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (net!=null && net.isAvailable() && net.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; 
        }
        }


     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
speech.setText(text);
}
```

Thank you,
Regards 
Jayakar V

Comment: Hello Jayakar thank you for your answer, I expected to have 2 separated classes, the idea is to call VRecognition.startRecognition(); then VRecognition.getResult(); from many classes.

Comment: Have you implemented is connected method... Bfore calling speech recognition @Nacho Silva

Comment: Its not necessary Jayakar the main app will run on jelly bean devices which offers offline recognition. But thx for the advice :)